# How to configure summary comment on method in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

When typing "///" above the method in Visual Studio, it generates XML summary. 
For example:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="par1"></param>
    /// <param name="par2"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string Foo(int par1, string par2)
    {
        return "";
    }
```

Is there a setting somewhere where I can stop adding the following line?

```
/// <returns></returns>
```

Comment: Besides declaring void methods, I dunno

Comment: Why not just delete it?

Comment: @RBarryYoung, extra step that some people forget to do. But mostly my own curiosity :)

Comment: @Roman, since your method return a string and the XML Documentation Comments default have the <returns></returns> line, if it is a void method, then this line will not be created. As far as I know, there is no such setting to auto remove it, sorry for this inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research and several comments, I don't believe there is such setting or feature to customize the auto addition of

```
//<returns></returns>
```

This applies to VS2017 and earlier. Maybe this will be come a feature sometime in the future.